# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException - Save GORM

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I'm a new developer for groovy grails and I have a table named user under the database test. I succeed to login to that database by using grails but I couldn't succeed to register the new user. I have used GORM to import into database but there is a strange error and I couldn't find any possible solution to fix this.

[image: ERROR I GET]

My **domain class**

```
package com.example.ulu

import grails.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
class User {

    String userName
    String password
    String fullName


    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
def registeruser = { 

    User a = new User()
    a.fullName("John")
    a.userName("burak")
    a.password("1") 
    a.save()


}
```

**Plug-in's and dependencies**

```
dependencies {

        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'

        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
        compile "javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final"
        compile "org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.5"
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5"
        runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final"

    }

    plugins {

        build ":tomcat:8.0.22"


        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.14"


        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    }
```

Comment: curious as to which guide misguided you in such a way. Did you just make it up or did you find the how to online somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.fullName("John")
a.userName("burak")
a.password("1")
```

this is all wrong. Groovy uses JavaBean notation, and the property-assignment must look like:

```
a.fullName = "John"
a.userName = "burak"
a.password ="1"
```

or

```
a.setFullName "John"
a.setUserName "burak"
a.setPassword "1"
```

or

```
a[ 'fullName' ] = "John"
a[ 'userName' ] = "burak"
a[ 'password' ] ="1"
```